# d3.js for showing workflow runtime state

Tags: d3.js

We are looking to graphically depict state of running workflows. For instance in the below screenshot, runtime state of a workflow is presented. The small green box below an activity indicates that the activity has been processed  -

[image: Workflow example]

I need to implement something similar for a workflow system. Users need to see the runtime state of workflow (what all activities are there in the flow) and which activities have already completed.

I was hoping to use D3 Visualization API to achieve this. I have a few questions regarding that -

1. Is it free or does it need a license
2. Can something like this be achieved in D3? I was looking at the examples, but couldn't find anything similar

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

3. Any other API which would be more appropriate for this kind of a requirement

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should realize that, unlike [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for example, D3 is not a collection of graphs or visualizations. It's a library (just like jQuery) that allows you to create said visualizations from scratch.

Now, to answer your questions:

1. > *Is it free or does it need a license*

   As stated on the bottom of [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/):

   > Library is released under [**BSD license**](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause). Copyright 2013 [**Mike Bostock**](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/).

   And [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_.28.22Revised_BSD_License.22.2C_.22New_BSD_License.22.2C_or_.22Modified_BSD_License.22.29) on BSD 3-clause license states that:

   > This version allows unlimited redistribution for any purpose as long as its copyright notices and the license's disclaimers of warranty are maintained. The license also contains a clause restricting use of the names of contributors for endorsement of a derived work without specific permission.
2. > *Can something like this be achieved in D3? I was looking at the examples, but couldn't find anything similar*

   Yes, this can be achieved. You might find some inspiration in [this directed graph editor example](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347).
3. > *Any other API which would be more appropriate for this kind of a requirement*

   For simple cases D3 itself should be sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar requirement, I was able to make such kind of chart using d3 :

[image]

You can find the code for same [here](https://github.com/neerajdembla212/d3-snake-chart).

In this i have used bootstrap panels as a content of each state, we could fulfill your requirement by tweaking some code to change position of boxes and direction of arrows.

I can help you modifying the code further if you need.

Hope this helps :) .

Comment: Hi, I have created a workflow(bpm shapes with drag drop) based on project requirement, but I am not able to understand a use case for this. Can I integrate with java at the backend to recieve json from d3js? I need a use case to practically create a small project to understand and fill the gaps. Can you please throw some light. Thanks

Comment: This inspired me to go this simpler route for my simple requirements; much cleaner than using a library.

Comment: Please provide full link. Hyperlink break sometime.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Please visit following link if you are not able to navigate

https://github.com/neerajdembla212/d3-snake-chart